# Optional ApiModelProperty appearing in JSON Swagger response with null value

Tags: json, rest, jackson, swagger

I am having trouble modifying a model class used by Swagger.
I would like to add new optional properties within a service response.
So I did modify my class like this :

```
@ApiModelProperty(required=false,value="This field is optional in response")
public String myNewProp;
```

Whenever I test my generated code, this field does appear in the response body even when it should not with null value :

> { "newProp": null }

Am I misunderstanding the "required=false" option ?
What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I just had to add this Jackson annotation for the given field :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@ApiModelProperty(required=false,value="This field is optional in response")
public String myNewProp;
```